# Many-to-Many relations in Vapor 3 with Fluent

Tags: mysql, swift, vapor

I was wondering how to create many-to-many relations in Vapor 3 using Fluent and FluentMySQL as described in the [Vapor 2 docs](https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/fluent/relations/)

Sadly, the [docs for Vapor 3](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/fluent/relations/) have not been updated yet and the implementation for the `Pivot` protocol has changed.

Here is what I'm trying to do: I have two classes, `User` and `Community`. A `Community` has `members` and `User`s can be members of multiple `Community`s.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
import Vapor
import FluentMySQL

final class Community: MySQLModel {
    var id: Int?
    //Community Attributes here
}

final class User: MySQLModel {
    var id: Int?
    //User Attributes here
}

extension Community {
    var members: Siblings<Community, User, Pivot<Community, User>> {
        return siblings()
    }
}
```

However, this causes the following compiler errors:

`Cannot specialize non-generic type 'Pivot'` and `Using 'Pivot' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Pivot' is not supported`.

I have seen that there is a protocol extension called `ModifiablePivot` but I don't know how to use it since there is no documentation or sample code anywhere.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fluent 3 no longer provides a default pivot like `Pivot` in Fluent 2. What you should do instead is create a type that conforms to `Pivot`. There are some helper types in `FluentMySQL` for this.

```
final class CommunityUser: MySQLPivot {
    // implement the rest of the protocol requirements
    var communityID: Community.ID
    var userID: User.ID
}
```

Then use the `CommunityUser` in place of `Pivot<Community, User>`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and both of the answers weren't sufficient for me, so i'm just posting my solution which worked for me.

```
// in CommunityUser.swift
import Vapor
import FluentMySQL


final class CommunityUser: MySQLPivot {

    typealias Left = User
    typealias Right = Community

    static var leftIDKey: LeftIDKey = \.userID
    static var rightIDKey: RightIDKey = \.communityID

    var id: Int?
    var userID: Int
    var communityID: Int

    init(id: Int?, userID: Int, communityID: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.userID = userID
        self.communityID = communityID
    }

}

// CommunityUser didn't conform to MySQLMigration
// This simple line solves the problem
extension CommunityUser: MySQLMigration { }
```

For me `CommunityUser` also needed to be migrated in the Database.

```
// in configure.swift
migrations.add(model: CommunityUser.self, database: .mysql)
```

Answer (score 1):

Full code:

```swift
import Vapor
import FluentSQLite

final class Community: SQLiteModel {
    var id: Int?
    //Community Attributes here
}

final class User: SQLiteModel {
    var id: Int?
    //User Attributes here
}

extension Community {
    var members: Siblings<Community, User, CommunityUser> {
        return siblings()
    }
}

final class CommunityUser: SQLitePivot {
    typealias Left = User
    typealias Right = Community
    static let leftIDKey: LeftIDKey = \.userID
    static let rightIDKey: RightIDKey = \.communityID
    var id: Int?
    var userID: Int
    var communityID: Int
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.